# How to open nested tables from power query, in new sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, power-query

In excel, I have a power query which loads a table with nested tables. In the query editor window, I can click the Table and drill down which is great.

Problem is, when I do save and close, and return to the regular excel view, and I see the table there, the nested tables, show as "Table" like a literal string. And if I click it, nothing happens, since it is just a string.

I would like it to open up the nested table in a new sheet for example.

How can I do this?

Comment: To present data from Power Query in Excel you need a "flat file". If you see "table" in the PQ editor then it is not flat. You need to complete the transformation. That should get you the full (flat) table into excel. to get that "drill down" funtionality on that table you can use subtotals, slicers (filters) or a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Each new sheet/table output from Power Query to Excel requires a separate Query definition in the Power Query Editor.

You can optimise your "code" by starting a new query using the "Reference" right-click option on your existing query - it will inherit the logic of that query.  Then you can add your steps to expand the table, drop / add columns etc as you like.  Load the new query into Excel as a new table on a new sheet.